# Facebook share count via jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am trying to get facebook's share count number to display in my blog with jQuery but its not working.  What is wrong with my script?

```
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              url = "http://www.yahoo.com/";

              $.getJSON("https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls="+url+"&format=json",
                  function(data) {
                      $('#fb-share').append(data.share_count);
              });
          })
      </script>

     <div id="fb-share"></div>
```

Comment: Where did you get that API URL from? This won't work, because to make this request you would need to run the script on `api.facebook.com`

Comment: @RGraham I got it from here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/10/26/extending-facebook-share/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?
                         urls=http://www.yahoo.com&format=json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Jsfiddle is down but have a look here: http://jsbin.com/OqOBEke/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: This works, but the source isn't wrapped in a JS call, or even in JSONp format. So how does it execute as JSONp?

Comment: @RGraham I just assumed that it was JSONP. But you're right, its not, so no need for the `dataType`

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to why it *does* work. Doesn't this break cross-domain policy?

Comment: @RGraham Everywhere I read it says that FB solves it using the JSONP format. But I'm just as confused as you, since it's obviously not JSONP format.